# Hide and Show Second form on Button Click

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, show-hide

I want to show another form(Form2) with button click. Basically When the button is clicked in Form1, another form(Form2) should show, this should not hide the Form1 though and should change the button text to "Hide Progress" in Form1. And when this button is clicked again the Form2 should hide and the text in button should change to "Show Progress".

Below is my effort to make this work. When I clicked the Show Progress Button, it brings the Form2 and changes the text in button as well. But when I clicked the button again instead of hiding the Form2, it opens another instance of Form2.

Probably reason behind is that, the bool value is not saved.

Here is my code for button event handler.

```
public partial class Main : Form
    {
       public string output_green, output_grey, output_blue, output_black;
       public bool visible;
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            output progressWindow = new output();

            if (visible == false)
            {
                progressWindow.Show();
                button1.Text = "Hide Progress";
                visible = true;
            }

            else
            {
                progressWindow.Show();
                button1.Text = "Show Progress";
                visible = false;

            }

        }
}
```

How can I achieve that I need to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem:**

Each time you click `button1` a **new** progressWindow has been initialized.

Also you are using `progressWindow.Show()` instead of `Hide()` in else part.

**Solution:**

Declare `progressWindow` out of `button1_Click`. And then initialize it from `button1_Click`. Now it will be initialized only once (using `if`).

```
output progressWindow = null;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
        if(progressWindow == null)
            progressWindow = new output();
        if (button1.Text == "Show Progress")
        {
            progressWindow.Show();
            button1.Text = "Hide Progress";
        }
        else
        {
            progressWindow.Hide();
            button1.Text = "Show Progress";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Raging Bull, It still doesn't hide the Form2

Comment: Yes your solutions initialize the Form2 only once not but the Form2 is not hidden when button is clicked

Comment: @AmritSharma: You are using `progressWindow.Show()` in the else part as well. That was the problem. Now I have updated my answer. Try it now.

Comment: It works perfectly, Now I got it Where I was wrong. Thanks Raging

Comment: I really don't like that last edit.  You are using the button's `Text` property as an information store now - this is never a good idea.  One property, one purpose.  The extra boolean is not necessary, but it's a better design than storing information where it doesn't belong.

Answer (score 0):

For a shorter solution where the progress window's lifetime persists with the main form :

```
    output progressWindow = new output();
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        progressWindow.Visible = !progressWindow.Visible;
        button1.Text = (progressWindow.Visible) ? "Hide Progress" : "Show Progress";
    }
```

Here you get rid of the need for the extra boolean since the progress form itself is fully capable of telling you whether it is visible or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
  // Creates a single instance only it it is request.
  private Output ProgressWindow
    {
      get 
          {
              return progressWindow?? (progressWindow= new Output(){Visible = false};
          }
    }

   private Output progressWindow;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
         ProgressWindow.Visible = !ProgressWindow.Visible;
         button1.Text = (ProgressWindow.Visible) ? "Hide Progress" : "Show Progress";

        }
    }
```